# Trying to print a specific item from a array, this being 'PBCM, Compact' but am currently unable to, please see below for error details

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here is my code :

```py
Phone = [["PBCM", "Compact"], ["BPSH", "Clam Shell"], ["RPSS", "RoboPhone - 5-inch screen and 64 GB memory"], ["RPLL", "RoboPhone - 6-inch screen and 256 GB memory"], ["YPLS", "Y-Phone Strandard - 6-inch screen and 64 GB memory"], ["YPLL", "Y-Phone Delux - 6-inch screen and 256 GB memory"], ["RTMS", "RoboTab - 8-inch screen and 64 GB memory"], ["RTLM", "RoboTab - 10-inch screen and 128 GB memory"], ["YTLM", "Y-Tab Standard - 10-inch and 128 GB memory"], ["YTLL", "Y-Tab Delux - 10-inch and 256 GB memory"]]

SIM = [["SMNO", "SIM Free (no SIM card purchased)"], ["RSST", "Pay As You Go (Sim card purchased)"]]

Case = [["SMNO", "Standard"], ["SMPG", "Luxury"]]

Charger = [["CGCR", "Car"], ["CGHM", "Home"]]

a = input("select phone item code: ")
if str(a) == "PBCM":
  for i in range (Phone(0,1)):
    print(i)
```

I get the error bellow :

```py
select phone item code: PBCM
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in range (Phone(0,1)):
"YTypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't access to list member with parentheses in python, they are reserved for function call. You have to use square brackets (`[]`) instead.

And to iterate through a list, you can use `for i in list`

```py
if str(a) == "PBCM":
  for i in Phone[0]:
    print(i[1])
```

I am not sure I get the point to the code though, see my suggestion bellow.

---

You might want to search the whole list to check against input. The following code will do it :

```py
a = input("select phone item code: ")

for i in Phone:
    if str(a) == i[0]:
        print(i[1])
```